# how to create the database inside the Postgres docker image using flyway

Tags: postgresql, docker, flyway

I have docker springboot application which is using docker Postgres database and flyway as a database migration tool but when I run `docker-compose up` it throws exception that

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "my_db" does not exist
```

the Question is how to create the database inside the Postgres docker image using flyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flyway deploys the defined scripts to a database. It doesn't create the database. You need one additional step, somewhere, that creates your my_db first, then you can run Flyway to do the deployment of all the database internals.